# Reactive cocoa: Stop a RACSignal after UIViewController is dealloc

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa

In my case, I presented a `containerViewController` consists of several `UIViewControllers`.

One of them, **controller A**, will send request to server every 10 seconds to get data. I used a `RACSignal` to do it:

`[[[RACSignal interval:10 onScheduler:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]] takeUntil:self.rac_willDeallocSignal] subscribeNext:DoSomeThing];`

But when the containerViewController is dismissed from the rootViewController, the signal still fired every 10 seconds, means `rac_willDeallocSignal` of **controller A** is not called. How can it be fixed?????

Thanks!!!

Comment: You'll have to provide more code to identify the problem. One candidate is the `DoSomething` block. What does it capture?

Comment: Hi @DaveLee, the DoSomeThing block captured a singleton `AFHTTPSessionManager` returns a signal that do the job, something like `[[self.clientManager getData] doError:subscribeNext:]`

Answer (score 6):

Maybe it is too late to answer this question, but yet it may be helpful for those who are looking for solution.

I have solved similar problem with creating separate signal when `UIViewController` will disappear, and used that signal as `takeUntil:` in the Interval signal. Code looks like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    RACSignal *rac_viewWillDisappear = 
        [self rac_signalForSelector:@selector(viewWillDisappear:)];
    [[[RACSignal interval:10 onScheduler:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]]
        takeUntil:rac_viewWillDisappear] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
            //Do what you need
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The interval signal is infinite, it will never complete. Consequently, any objects that are strongly captured in the subscription blocks will also live on indefinitely, and thus their `willDeallocSignal` will not do anything. There are two ways to work around this:

1. Capture objects weakly
2. Explicitly dispose of the subscription

The first case is preferable. In this case, you could use `@weakify(self)` outside of the block and `@strongify(self)` inside the block.

The second option is more of a clumsy brute approach. I wouldn't recommend it.

See RAC's [Memory Management](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/e32d77b48064e8e71e1d59cd241de054e8150180/Documentation/MemoryManagement.md).

Comment: Implemented the first solution but still not work, then I make the `containViewController` post a notification when dismiss and it works!

Comment: Code: `[[[RACSignal interval:10 onScheduler:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]] takeUntil:[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] rac_addObserverForName:kSystemQuitNotification object:nil]] subscribeNext:DoSomething]`

Comment: Glad you were able to get something to work. Your solution is less than ideal though. If you run into it again you might want to figure out how to break the retain cycle rather than using the notification approach everywhere.